# FormData without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-data

hi there I have his form for upload file

```
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e .preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "index2.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            ...
```

in form html:

```
 <form id="form" action="index2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" /><br/>
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

it works. butnow I want remove button. I want upload automaticly when I select file.

```
          $.ajax({
                url: "index2.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData("#form"),
                contentType: false,

                 ...
```

But not works. can please help me to do that?

Comment: You will need to wait until the file has finished uploading.  What have tried?

Comment: ok,I do not want submit and than  start upload,I want when select file from localhost, start upload file immediately

Answer (score 1):

you can add a drop zone (just drag and drop). look at AutoUpload: true.

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "/somewhere.com/here",
  dropZone: $("#picturezone"),
  autoUpload: true,
  done: function (e, data) {
   $("#pic").attr("src", URl + data.result.name + "?" + d.gettime());
 }
 }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
  //Do something while it is uploading.
 });
```

Comment: thanks, dropzone.js is about 64 kb, why Must I use it when I can do it with less 5 kb codding?

Comment: I like it more. I can usually show the resulting upload on the zone. But is all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to listen for the onChange event for that input.

Your code should be like this:

```
$('#uploadImage').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "index2.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData("#form"),
            contentType: false,

             ...
    });
});
```

Comment: The `FormData` constructor doesn't take a CSS selector string as an argument. You need `new FormData($("#form")[0])` to get the actual element.